# Use of screen on terminal is blocked by length of user name

Tags: macos, terminal, username, gnu-screen

I am a user of screen on terminal, but i tried to mount a screen on my Macbook and results in this warning:

```
$ screen
LoginName too long - sorry.
```

I read on web and the suggestion is change the username of my computer, but I am the only user and the administrator of the computer, and I have a lot of information in my session.

Can I do something?

Comment: There's a [bug report](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?21653) for this. It also chokes if `$HOME` is longer than 25 characters.

Comment: @NPE: Since one solution does involve modifying the source code, I suggest that it's topical here.

Comment: @NPE: But if it's a better fit for superuser, that's fine with me.

Comment: @KeithThompson: To be honest, when I voted, I wasn't expecting the answer to deal with the source code. I now think both sites are equally suited for the question and your answer. I'll let the community decide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug, [reported here](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?21653). It also chokes if `$HOME` is longer than 25 characters.

I was able to work around this by applying a patch (which increases the limit from 20 to 50) and rebuilding from source.

The patch is in [this message](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-devel/2011-05/msg00000.html). It doesn't apply to the screen-4.0.3 sources downloaded from ftp.gnu.org; apparently it depends on some unreleased changes added after that.

(Note: When I downloaded the patch, it named it `bin4fE4KxGNNI.bin`; I manually renamed it to `gnuscreen-21653.patch`.)

So I grabbed the latest `screen` sources from git:

```
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/screen.git
```

applied the patch:

```
patch -p 1 < gnuscreen-21653.patch
```

then built from source:

```
./autogen.sh
cd src
./configure --prefix=/where/you/want/to/install
make
make install
```

This gave me a `screen` executable that I can run from `/home/accountwithaverylongusername` on my Linux system. It should work the same way on OSX.

If your user name is longer than 50 characters, you can probably just update the constant after applying the patch.

I hope this patch, or something like it, will appear in the next release of GNU screen.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was kind of uncomfortable with installing from source, but these instructions were great. Just one thing: the file `autogen.sh` was in `src` in my checkout. That probably changed after you answered this question, but perhaps you could include it in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I worked around the same bug by using [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) instead of screen.

Answer (score 1):

Screen-4.3.1 has solved this bug. Just do the following:

1-Download Screen-4.3.1

```
wget http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/screen.html
```

2-Decompress

```
tar -zxvf screen-4.3.1.tar.gz
```

3-Go to directory

```
cd screen-4.3.1
```

4-Run configure to create Makefile

```
./configure
```

5-Make and install

```
make
make install
```

6-It will probably ask you to do the following copy manually:

```
sudo cp etc/etcscreenrc /etc/
```

Comment: Installed `4.03.01` via `brew install screen` and still have the same `LoginName too long - sorry.` error.